# Printing two dimensional in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, printing

I want to output something like this in JavaScript.

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I am trying

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var i ,j ;

for(i=1;i<=6;i++){
  for(j=1;j<=6;j++){
    document.write('*');    
    document.write('<br>');    
  }
  document.write('<br>');   
}
</script>
```

definitely this code doesn't work the way I need it to..I am confused about how I can print `*` in my required way...

Comment: Look how often your inner loop runs. Look where you print line breaks. Think again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the inner loop to

```
for (j=1; j<=i; j++) {
             ^---  the important bit
    document.write('*');
}
document.write('<br>');
```

That way the inner loop prints up to `i` worth of `*` chars, and the outer loop takes care of stopping things when you've got 6 lines done. e.g.

```
i | j     | printed
-------------------
1 | 1     | *
2 | 1,2   | **
3 | 1,2,3 | ***
etc...
```

Comment: no doubt, it works fine and more like CS101

Answer (score 2):

You only need one loop:

```
function writeStars(n) {
    var m = '',
        t = [];

    for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
      m += '*';
      t.push(m);
    }
    return t.join('<br>') + '<br>';
}

document.write(writeStars(6));
```

Comment: works flawlessly...but its more like CS201, I was just remembering those days and I remember teacher did this example, but now, I wasnt able to do this, thanks

Comment: How you do it probably depends on whether the purpose of the lesson is to teach nested loops or alternative logic. ;-)

Comment: to be true, I was not thinking nested loop or alternative logic, I was remembering my college life a few years back when I tried creating this example , thanka billion for this guideline